# user specified function in R program

Tags: r, functional-programming

I would like to create a function which can be use for different sets of data. This is my function (I make it as source code):

```
#Log-likelihood function
likfunc<-function(para,dat){
  alpha<-para[1]
  lambda<-para[2]
  a<-log(para[1])+log(para[2])+(para[1]-1)*log(dat$z)
  b<-para[2]*(dat$z)^para[1]
  return((dat$d*a)+b)
}
```

Then I try to run the following code (this is 1st set of data):

```
library(maxLik)
set.seed(201)
u<-runif(20,min=0,max=1) #to simulate t
c<-rexp(20,rate=0.05)
t<-(-log(u)/0.5)^(1/2) #initial vale alpha=2,lambda=0.5
z<-pmin(t,c) 
d<-as.numeric(c>t)     
samp<-cbind(t,c,z,d)
data<-as.data.frame(samp)

mle<-maxLik(logLik=likfunc(para,data),start=c(alpha=2,lambda=0.5))
mle
```

But the R return: 
    Error in likfunc(para, data) : object 'para' not found

I am doing simulation. Previously I run the function every time when there is a new dataset. Then I get an advice as my code will make the R work more and it take very long time to complete the simulation. Anyone can help on this? Thank you.

Comment: `: object 'para' not found` - you don't have an object called `para`, and you're trying to pass it into the function when you call `maxLik(logLik=likfunc(para,data)...`

Comment: to fix it add a `dat=data` argument and only pass the function to `maxLik`: `maxLik(logLik=likfunc,dat=data,start=c(alpha=2,lambda=0.5))`. Also it seems, that your likelihood returns a vector not a scalar.

Comment: @J.R you are right! I get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First the error message is because you haven't defined object **para** in the global environment. On the other hand maxLik has a function as argument, so instead of evaluating the function you should just call it:

```
library(maxLik)
# Define the function only with para as argument
likfunc<-function(para){
alpha<-para[1]
lambda<-para[2]
# Call dat inside the function as it will be defined in the global environment
a<-log(para[1])+log(para[2])+(para[1]-1)*log(dat$z)
b<-para[2]*(dat$z)^para[1]
return((dat$d*a)+b)
}    
# Your example
set.seed(201)
u<-runif(20,min=0,max=1) #to simulate t
c<-rexp(20,rate=0.05)
#para <- c(alpha = 2, lambda = 0.5) #initial value alpha=2,lambda=0.5
t<-(-log(u)/2)^(0.5) 
z<-pmin(t,c) 
d<-as.numeric(c>t)     
samp<-cbind(t,c,z,d)
# dat defined in the global environment
dat<-as.data.frame(samp)
mle<-maxLik(logLik=likfunc,start=c(alpha=2,lambda=0.5))
mle
```

Comment: Thanks. My intention is to make the likfunc to be available for many datasets. The function works well for single dataset. Let me explain more detail on my problem. I would like to simulate 1000 datasets. In each dataset, I will perform the maxLik which require the likfunc. For each simulated datasets, I will perform nonparametric bootstrap and obtain another 2000 bootstrap samples. Again, I will perform maxLik on these bootstrap samples. I apply the likfunc in the loop and it makes the R too slow. Thats why I am thinking of method to call the likfunc 1 time and only change the dataset.